# Global Auto Save Visited Mode

Tags: auto-save

I can't get auto-save visited mode to work.

All I have in my config is this:

```
(setq auto-save-visited-mode t)
(setq auto-save-visited-interval 2)
```

Should I need to enable anything else to get auto save visited mode to work?;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-h v auto-save-visited-mode`:

> **Setting this variable directly does not take effect;**
> either *customize* it
> or call the function `auto-save-visited-mode`.

Use `(auto-save-visited-mode)` to enable it, `(auto-save-visited-mode -1)` to disable.

If you want to enable it globally, use:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(auto-save-visited-mode t))
```